# React: npm start - windows cannot find localhost

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ubuntu, npm, localhost

I am trying to follow tutorials for basic react-build-app.

**ENVIRONMENT**

I am using Ubuntu on Windows 10.

Node version: v13.3.0

NPM version: 6.13.1

So far I did,

`npm install -g create-react-app`

`create-react-app calculator`

`cd calculator`

`npm start`

**PROBLEM**

When I run npm  start, I get pop up dialog from windows saying, `Windows cannot find '\https://localhost:3000/\'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.`
[Here is a screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EMhp.png)

However, in the cli, I see

````
 Local:            http://localhost:3000/
 On Your Network:  http://192.168.56.1:3000/

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.```
````

But when I open my browser and go to http://localhost:3000/, I only see a blank page, and not the normal React logo.

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

I should see the react logo when going to http://localhost:3000/, and not receive and error.

**ATTEMPTS**

- Updated nodejs and npm.
- Changed ports using package.json. Also tried
  using .env file to change port. Same error.
- Uninstalled and re-installed ubuntu 18.04 LTS and used NVM to install nodejs and npm.

**WORKAROUND**
I got tired of fixing error after error with linux, so I just set up npm and nodejs on windows instead. ran create-react-app on windows cli and it worked the first time. Told me something else was listening on the port i was trying to open, so prompted me to change port. I said yes. Now I get the landing page I was looking for.

I am very new at this and have been trying to figure this out for a couple days now, I would appreciate any advice. Thank you.

Comment: did you mean to add those extra slashes? `http://localhost:3000/` should work in your browser

Comment: I can successfully go to localhost:3000. But, I do not see the react logo that we should see after a simple create-react-app my-app. The extra slashes that you see is what the windows error is displaying.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue after updating to react-scripts 3.3.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a WSL specific issue with one of the dependencies of `react-scripts`, more specifically `open` version `7.0.0`.

To resolve, you can:

- switch to `react-scripts 3.2.0` in your package.json, or
- run `npm start` from something else than WSL (e.g. Powershell), or
- wait for `open` and `react` to fix the issue

Bug report in React Scripts:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8081

And the corresponding bug report in open:
https://github.com/sindresorhus/open/issues/154

Comment: `npm uninstall react-scripts --save && npm install react-scripts@3.2.0 --save`

Answer (score 1):

According to this post in the bug report in open the culprit is lines 76 & 77 of index.js in node_modules/open. If you comment them out then it works fine.

Link to comment:
https://github.com/sindresorhus/open/issues/154#issuecomment-562509596